# Perfmon - Redirector current command 0 result

Tags: windows-server-2008, performance-tuning, perfmon

I'd like to monitor how many SMB connections there are at any given time for my 2008R2 file server, but when I add Redirector/Current Commands in perfmon, I get 0 results.
This KB from Microsoft isn't exactly helpful either: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2523382
It mearly confirms there is an issue, but doesn't provide a work around.

How would I go about getting the current number of SMB connections?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken, the Redirector perfmon counter object is the client side, not the server side. On the file server I believe you need to look at the Server|Sessions counter to see how many active SMB sessions exist on the server.

Comment: It's the same on our citrix servers that would logins and all SMB connections.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Can you rephrase it?

Comment: Sorry for the terrible English.  There are 0 results when I add Redirector/Current Commands on the client side (our citrix servers).  Even when they are densely populated with users.

Comment: My apologies if my answer wasn't quite clear. What I mean to say is that you should add the perfmon counter for Server|Sessions on the server. That way you see all sessions to the server. So, you'll be looking at this from the server, not the client.

Comment: Will this be the equivalent to how many SMB connections there are currently on the server?